# Ionic framework - Config.xml

Tags: android, ionic-framework, configuration-files

I need to modify the config.xml file, so when compiling for Android I take these permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

I did it this way, in config.xml:

```
<platform name="android">
    <icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-ldpi-icon.png" density="ldpi"/>
    <icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-mdpi-icon.png" density="mdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-hdpi-icon.png" density="hdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" density="xhdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxhdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" density="land-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" density="land-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" density="land-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xxxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" density="port-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" density="port-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xxxhdpi"/>

     <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="10" />
    <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="21" />

    <config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/*"> 
        <supports-screens 
            android:anyDensity="true" 
            android:largeScreens="true" 
            android:normalScreens="true" 
            android:resizeable="true" 
            android:smallScreens="true" 
            android:xlargeScreens="true" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />    

        <application 
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true" 
            android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:supportsRtl="true">

            <activity 
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" 
                android:label="@string/activity_name" 
                android:launchMode="singleTop" 
                android:name="MainActivity" 
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
                 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">

                <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        </application>
    </config-file>

  </platform>
```

But then when generating manifest has only the `INTERNET` permission, not `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE`.

**1.** Is that wrong? Must I add the permission manually to the AndroidManifest.xml?

And another query:

**2.** How do I indicate the value for the string "launcher_name"? In string.xml can change it, but when compiling steps to a default value.

Answer (score 1):

1. There shouldn't be any harm in just adding it manually to the AndroidManifest.xml so that is probably your best option.

For both 1 and 2, just to confirm, you are editing the config.xml that is at the base of your project? There is another one that gets created in platform/android/res/xml that you should not be editing because it will always be replaced.