# Failed to load resource *.html file in cordova app

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, visual-studio-2015

I am learning cordova/ionic/angular mobile application using visual studio 2015 by doing a POC. Its working fine in ripple. But when I try to run this application on real android device, it simply refuse to load my html templates saying Failed to load resource *.html.

My html template file is in folder named view.

I think I am missing something in state provider configuration so I am pasting example code

```
angular.module('ModuleName')
.config(function config($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state("index", {
        url: "",
        controller: "UserController as UC",
        templateUrl: "view/UserEventInformation.html"
    })
})

.config(function config($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state("Dashboard", {
        url: "/Dashboard",
        controller: "UserController as UC",
        templateUrl: "view/Dashboard.html"
    })
})
```

Comment: did you set the required permissions correctly? see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29923135/ionic-framework-config-xml

Comment: Do you have somewhere in your code the module definition with the injected dependencies: `angular.module('ModuleName', ['ionic'])` ?

Comment: Yes. angular.module('ModuleName', ['ionic', 'ui.router']); in different JS file which is getting included prior to code mentioned above.

Comment: If you create a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/) with the structure of your app we can try to help.